# How to get all horizontal Frame lines in Grid, including topmost and bottom-most?

Tags: output-formatting, frame

How can I get the option `Frame` in `TextGrid` to do all horizontal lines, including top and bottom?

I want:

----
a b
----
c d
----
e f
----

The closest I get is with the following command:

```
TextGrid[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}},  Frame -> {{False, False}, All}]
```

which produces a grid with horizontal lines but misses top and bottom:

a b
----
c d
----
e f

I tried several things, but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 TextGrid[{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}},Dividers->{False,All}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I just [found](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/FormatATableOfData.html) that answer haha. Thanks.